# how to get year from date in HQL for Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, hibernate, hql

```
List employees = session.createQuery("FROM Employee where date1 between '04-APR-04 02.27.05.187000 AM' and '04-APR-14 02.27.05.187000 AM' and YEAR('04-APR-04 02.27.05.187000 AM')=YEAR('04-APR-04 02.27.05.187000 AM')").list();
```

I am getting this Issue:

```
    Hibernate: select emThrployee0_.id as id2_, employee0_.firstName as firstName2_, employee0_.lastName as lastName2_, employee0_.date1 as date4_2_ from emp1 employee0_ where (employee0_.date1 between '04-APR-04 02.27.05.187000 AM' and '04-APR-14 02.27.05.187000 AM') and extract(year from '04-APR-04 02.27.05.187000 AM')=extract(year from '04-APR-04 02.27.05.187000 AM')
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2214)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2095)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2090)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:388)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1121)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:79)
    at main.StoreData.listEmployees(StoreData.java:68)
    at main.StoreData.main(StoreData.java:57)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-30076: invalid extract field for extract source

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:743)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:216)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:799)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1038)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:839)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1133)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3285)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3329)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1778)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:662)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2211)
    ... 9 more
```

i need year from date in hibernate for Oracle 
but this code working in Sql server but in Oracle is not Working.
i try but i can't solve pls help any if knows

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Implicit conversions aren't as accomidating in Oracle as they are in SQL Server.  Look at stuffing your date time strings into the TO_DATE() function in your query.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm

Comment: I got Ans:FROM Employee  where date1 between '2014-04-04 08:58:45.000' and '2014-04-14 08:58:45.000' and extract(year from date1)=to_char(to_timestamp('2014-04-10 08:58:45.000','yyyy-mm-rr hh:mi:ss.ff am'),'yyyy')

Answer (score 0):

I would try reading the documentation because your query should be structured this way:

```
Select * FROM table t WHERE t.column...
```

You can try something like the following:

```
"SELECT * FROM Employee e WHERE e.date1 > '2013-01-01' AND e.date1 <'2014-01-01'"
```

This will get all columns from your employee table and you can experiment with dates in [these](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp) formats. Using those formats you can use the function `YEAR(date)`.

Comment: year(date) query is working in sql server.what is alternative query for Oracle in HQL.

Comment: It is part of Hibernate's documentation as well your date is just in the wrong format.